# Convert Input to Direction

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

Given input in the form `<n1>, <n2>` where number can be -1, 0, or 1, return the corresponding [cardinal direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction). Positive numbers move East in the x-axis and South in the y-axis, Negative numbers move West in the x-axis and North in the y-axis.

Output must be in the form `South East`, `North East`, `North`. It is case-sensitive.

If the input is 0, 0, your program must return `That goes nowhere, silly!`.

## Sample Input/Outpot:

`1, 1` -> `South East`

`0, 1` -> `South`

`1, -1` -> `North East`

`0, 0` -> `That goes nowhere, silly!`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Loosely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21927/convert-degrees-to-one-of-the-32-points-of-the-compass?rq=1)

Comment: Some examples with W, NW and SW are needed.

Comment: @seshoumara I'm on mobile, so no backticks, but NW would be -1, -1

Comment: Are trailing Spaces allowed?

Comment: Uhh... Sure, I guess. As long as it looks the same.

Comment: Can we take `+1` instead of `1`?

Comment: No (15 chars minimum to comment)

Comment: Can we take the numbers in the opposite order? `1, 0` is "South"?

Comment: No. Must be x, y.

Comment: Can we take numbers as two separate command-line arguments?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, you can.

Answer (score 11):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
`
SÆ 
NÆ° `·gV +`
E†t
Wƒt`·gU ª`T•t goƒ Í2€e, Ðéy!
```

#### Explanation

```
                      // Implicit: U, V = inputs
`\nSÆ \nNÆ° `       // Take the string "\nSouth \nNorth ".
·                     // Split it at newlines, giving ["", "South ", "North "].
gV                    // Get the item at index V. -1 corresponds to the last item.
+                     // Concatenate this with
`\nE†t\nWƒt`·gU       // the item at index U in ["", "East", "West"].
ª`T•t goƒ Í2€e, Ðéy!  // If the result is empty, instead take "That goes nowhere, silly!".
                      // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/AFXy4jUOBy@9w26ENCgmHtqeHKWgncLkeaivhCj/UXAISCVU4tCoh5NDUEoX0/EPNCod7jQ41pOooHJ5weGWl4v//hgq6hgA)

Comment: Um... I... ??? How on earth does this work? Does Japt have like some fancy things that replace common character pairs?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes, Japt uses the [shoco compression library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) which replaces common pairs of lowercase characters with a single byte.

Comment: Okay, that's really cool! I'll look into that, see if I can make any use out of it.

Answer (score 8):

## Python, <s>101</s> 87 bytes

Really naive solution.

```
lambda x,y:['','South ','North '][y]+['','West','East'][x]or'That goes nowhere, silly!'
```

Thanks to @Lynn for saving 14 bytes! Changes: Using the string.split method actually makes it longer ;_; And also, negative indexes exist in python.

Comment: You can cut it down to 87 like this: `lambda x,y:('','South ','North ')[y]+('','East','West')[x]or'That goes nowhere, silly!'`

Comment: I found a neat way to get some directions, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it will work for this challenge. Figured I'd share it anyways (perhaps someone craftier than I can figure out how to deal with its problems, like when x or y = 0): `lambda x,y:'North htuoS'[::x][:6]+'EastseW'[::y][:4]` Edit: it likely will now be too long, but you can make the second slicing `[:6*x**2]`, likewise for the East/West string, if you can circumvent the error on the first slicing.

Comment: @Lynn `lambda x,y:('North ','South ')[y+1]+('West','East')[x+1]or'That goes nowhere, silly!'` is shorter by 2 bytes

Comment: @Lynn Oh, thanks! (I forgot about negative indexes!)

Comment: @DeadPossum That won't work because it will return `South East` for `(0, 0)`. Thank you though!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah, I missed that

Comment: Here's a working variant of my alternate solution; I'm bummed that it's unfortunately 99 bytes (it would be closer if it didn't need the `or 1`).

`lambda x,y:'North htuoS'[::y or 1][:6*y*y]+'EastseW'[::x or 1][:4*x*x]or"That goes nowhere, silly!"`

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 101 Bytes

```
[,$b,$a]=$argv;echo$a|$b?[North,"",South][1+$a]." ".[West,"",East][1+$b]:"That goes nowhere, silly!";
```

Comment: It's a long time since I programmed in PHP, but how does it know North, South, West and East are strings without double-quotes around them? Is this because of the empty String that shares the same array? If yes, does this also mean you cannot have an array with different types at once (like an array with both a string and an integer)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen North is a constant http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php If the constant not exists it will be interpreted as string. An array in PHP can contain different types. strings can be specified in four ways http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 79 bytes

```perl6
{<<'' East South North West>>[$^y*2%5,$^x%5].trim||'That goes nowhere, silly!'}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#RY6xCsIwGAb3PsWnWJPIb7GCLmo3VxcFBWuh1GiF1kgStcH22avi4HIc3HJ3I/GYBtnMKx36mTpKLNrXfM4YlqmxWKu7zbFS@sOtNDaK9r3EDcb@hHpJ5U8OgdWXsq7ZJk8tzkoaXNUzl1oSzKUoXIc17Ulp8GFIIwoFdn8dRuBxRbETeHmASR04r8iJ4FRazvyxYYIEoRvbLuE796s3qQuvad8)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$x｣ and ｢$y｣

  << '' East South North West >>\ # list of 5 strings
  [                               # index into that with:

    # use a calculation so that the results only match on 0
    $^y * 2 % 5, # (-1,0,1) => (3,0,2) # second parameter
    $^x % 5      # (-1,0,1) => (4,0,1) # first parameter

  ]
  .trim  # turn that list into a space separated string implicitly
         # and remove leading and trailing whitespace

  ||     # if that string is empty, use this instead
  'That goes nowhere, silly!'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <strike>106</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>97</strike> 93 bytes

It's a very simple approach. It consists of a few ternary operators nested together -

```
f=a=>b=>a|b?(a?a>0?"South ":"North ":"")+(b?b>0?"East":"West":""):"That goes nowhere, silly!"
```

**Test Cases**

```js
f=a=>b=>a|b?(a?a>0?"South ":"North ":"")+(b?b>0?"East":"West":""):"That goes nowhere, silly!"

console.log(f(1729)(1458));
console.log(f(1729)(-1458));
console.log(f(-1729)(1458));
console.log(f(-1729)(-1458));
console.log(f(0)(1729));
console.log(f(0)(-1729));
console.log(f(1729)(0));
console.log(f(-1729)(0));
```

Comment: `a!=0` can be replaced by just `a`, since 0 is falsy and all other values are truthy. Also, taking input in currying syntax is shorter, and the array appoach is also shorter.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the suggestion! I have edited the answer. Now, I am beating the PHP and Python solutions! All because of you!!! Thanks!

Comment: Save another byte by doing `f=a=>b=>` and calling the function like `f(1729)(1458)`; which is the `currying syntax` that @Luke mentioned.

Comment: You can safely use `a|b` instead of `a||b`. Assuming that the input only consists of -1, 0 or 1 (which is unclear to me), you could replace `a>0` and `b>0` with `~a` and `~b`.

Comment: Also, you don't need these parentheses: `a?(...):""` / `b?(...):""`

Comment: Are you sure you need the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: @Luke I think you should post it as an answer!

Comment: I don't think you need any of the parentheses ;)

Comment: He does... These parentheses cannot be left out: `a|b?(...)+(...):""`, all others can, saving 4B in total.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks a lot! I removed 4 of them. The rest 2 are necessary are necessary, as Luke mentions.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

```
a=>b=>["North ","","South "][b+1]+["West","","East"][a+1]||"That goes nowhere, silly!"
```

## Explanation

Call it with currying syntax (`f(a)(b)`). This uses array indices. If both `a` and `b` are 0, the result is a falsy empty string. In that case, the string after the `||` is returned.

## Try it

Try all test cases here:

```js
let f=
a=>b=>["North ","","South "][b+1]+["West","","East"][a+1]||"That goes nowhere, silly!"

for (let i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
    for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
        console.log(`${i}, ${j}: ${f(i)(j)}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 156 bytes

```
@set s=
@for %%w in (North.%2 South.-%2 West.%1 East.-%1)do @if %%~xw==.-1 call set s=%%s%% %%~nw
@if "%s%"=="" set s= That goes nowhere, silly!
@echo%s%
```

The `for` loop acts as a lookup table to filter when the (possibly negated) parameter equals -1, and concatenating the matching words. If nothing is selected then the silly message is printed instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 56 bytes

```
N¬¥0?`T•t goƒ Í2€e, Ðéy!`:` SÆ NÆ°`¸gV +S+` E†t Wƒt`¸gU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@93aM2hpQb2CSGHppYopOcfalY43Gt0qCFVR@HwhMMrKxUTrBIUgg@3cSj4HW47tCHh0I70MAXtYO0EBddDbSUK4YeaS0Biof//G@oYAgA) | [Test Suite](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@58bWh0dGhZrG2oNorSDtTVA9KE1h5YaGNgnhByaWqKQnn@oWeFwr9GhhlQdhcMTDq@sVEywSlAIPtzGoeB3uO3QhoRDO9LDFIB6ExRcD7WVKIQfai4BiYX@/x8drWuoo2sYqwOiDSAUkMcVbQARNQALGkDEoCohCkHqYnWDAA)

#### Explanation:

```
N¬¥0?`Tt go Í2e, Ðéy!`:` SÆ NÆ°`¸gV +S+` Et Wt`¸gU
Implicit U = First input
         V = Second input

N¬¥0?`...`:` ...`qS gV +S+` ...`qS gU
N¬                                                     Join the input (0,0 → "00")
  ¥0                                                   check if input is roughly equal to 0. In JS, "00" == 0
    ?                                                  If yes:
      ...                                               Output "That goes nowhere, silly!". This is a compressed string
     `   `                                              Backticks are used to decompress strings
          :                                            Else:
           ` ...`                                       " South North" compressed
                 qS                                     Split on " " (" South North" → ["","South","North"])
                   gV                                   Return the string at index V
                     +S+                                +" "+ 
                        ` ...`                          " East West" compressed
                              qS gU                     Split on spaces and yield string at index U
```

Comment: Hint: `00` is *exactly* the same as `0`, as the extra digit gets removed ;)

Comment: The second-best solution yet no upvote. I upvote for you.

Answer (score 2):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 100 + 1(r flag) = 101 bytes

```sed
s:^-1:We:
s:^1:Ea:
s:-1:Nor:
s:1:Sou:
s:(.*),(.*):\2th \1st:
s:0...?::
/0/cThat goes nowhere, silly!
```

By design, sed executes the script as many times as there are input lines, so one can do all the test cases in one run, if needed. The TIO link below does just that.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#FYixCgIxEET7fEXsVLK5XcttrGxtFGwO4ZBgDo5byUbEnzdmi5l5b5ryHYhviV0n4tNk0J@zFCPii7wNtnG/C1Y8Hmr2I2m1G2OMR2Y34PC45qn6pyT1q3xyKil4nZflu2kNAzoM1APkqAsF2y5gBqZg/pNXnWXVBuUP)**

**Explanation:**

```sed
s:^-1:We:                         # replace '-1' (n1) to 'We'
s:^1:Ea:                          # replace '1' (n1) to 'Ea'
s:-1:Nor:                         # replace '-1' (n2) to 'Nor'
s:1:Sou:                          # replace '1' (n2) to 'Sou'
s:(.*),(.*):\2th \1st:            # swap the two fields, add corresponding suffixes
s:0...?::                         # delete first field found that starts with '0'
/0/cThat goes nowhere, silly!     # if another field is found starting with '0',
                                  #print that text, delete pattern, end cycle now
```

The remaining pattern space at the end of a cycle is printed implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>84</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @seshoumara for suggesting `0...?` instead of `0\w* ?`*

```
(.+) (.+)
$2th $1st
^-1
Nor
^1
Sou
-1
We
1
Ea
0...?

^$
That goes nowhere, silly!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivoaetqQAiuFSMSjIUVAyLS7jidA25/PKLuOIMuYLzS7mAvPBULkMu10QuAz09PXsurjgVrpCMxBKF9PzUYoW8/PKM1KJUHYXizJycSsX//w0UDLkMwdgAiIG6DUCEriGUNAARIEEDAA)

Comment: The output is wrong. OP wants positive numbers to move S in the y-axis and negative numbers to move N.

Comment: @seshoumara Right, fixed it for same bytecount (just had to swap `Nor` and `Sou`)

Comment: Ok. Also, you can shave 1 byte by using `0...?`.

Comment: @seshoumara Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
õ'†Ô'…´)èUõ„ƒÞ „„¡ )èXJ™Dg_i“§µ—±æÙ,Ú¿!“'Tì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394q/qjhgWHpwDJZYe2aB5eEXp466OGeccmHZ6nAKSB6NBCBaBwhNejlkUu6fGZjxrmHFp@CKhmyqGNh5cdnqlzeNah/YpAUfWQw2v@/zfk0jUEAA)

**Explanation**

```
õ'†Ô'…´)                                       # push the list ['','east','west']
        èU                                     # index into this with first input
                                               # and store the result in X
          õ„ƒÞ „„¡ )                           # push the list ['','south ','north ']
                    èXJ                        # index into this with 2nd input
                                               # and join with the content of X
                       ™                       # convert to title-case
                        Dg_i                   # if the length is 0
                            “§µ—±æÙ,Ú¿!“       # push the string "hat goes nowhere, silly!"
                                        'Tì    # prepend "T"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/f3393e3949a9c9bdf47151cabd6bbf26), <s>95</s> 102 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
(a,b)=>(a|b)==0?"That goes nowhere, silly!":(b<0?"North ":b>0?"South ":"")+(a<0?"West":a>0?"East":"");
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
( a, b ) => ( a | b ) == 0
    ? "That goes nowhere, silly!"
    : ( b < 0 ? "North " : b > 0 ? "South " : "" ) +
      ( a < 0 ? "West" : a > 0 ? "East" : "" );
```

---

**Ungolfed readable**

```cs
// A bitwise OR is perfomed
( a, b ) => ( a | b ) == 0

    // If the result is 0, then the 0,0 text is returned
    ? "That goes nowhere, silly!"
    
    // Otherwise, checks against 'a' and 'b' to decide the cardinal direction.
    : ( b < 0 ? "North " : b > 0 ? "South " : "" ) +
      ( a < 0 ? "West" : a > 0 ? "East" : "" );
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;

namespace Namespace {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Func<Int32, Int32, String> f = ( a, b ) =>
                ( a | b ) == 0
                    ? "That goes nowhere, silly!"
                    : ( b < 0 ? "North " : b > 0 ? "South " : "" ) +
                      ( a < 0 ? "West" : a > 0 ? "East" : "" );

            for( Int32 a = -1; a <= 1; a++ ) {
                for( Int32 b = -1; b <= 1; b++ ) {
                    Console.WriteLine( $"{a}, {b} = {f( a, b )}" );
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.1** - `+ 7 bytes` - Wrapped snippet into a function.
- **v1.0** -  `95 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

*I'm a ghost, boo!*

Comment: That's a code snippet you need to wrap it in a function i.e. add the `(a,b)=>{...}` bit

Comment: You can use currying to save a byte `a=>b=>`, might not need the `()` around the `a|b`, you might be able to use interpolated strings to get the string built up nicer as well

Comment: Completely forgot to wrap into a function :S. For the `()` around the `a|b`, I do need it, otherwise `Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'`. I've also tried the interpolated strings, but didn't give much though due to the `""` giving me errors.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 40 bytes

```
Ṛị"“¡ƘƓ“¡+9“»,“wµ“¡ḳ]“»Kt⁶ȯ“¬ɼ¬<¬O÷ƝḤẎ6»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w56yHu7uVHjXMObTw2Ixjk8EMbUsQtVsHSJYf2goWerhjcyxY0LvkUeO2E@tB7DUn9xxaY3Nojf/h7cfmPtyx5OGuPrNDu////2@oo6BrCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 151 bytes

```
func d(x:Int,y:Int){x==0&&y==0 ? print("That goes nowhere, silly!") : print((y<0 ? "North " : y>0 ? "South " : "")+(x<0 ? "West" : x>0 ? "East" : ""))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 95 bytes.

This simply displays the element of the array, and if there's nothing, just displays the "default" message.

```
echo['North ','','South '][$argv[1]+1].[East,'',West][$argv[2]+1]?:'That goes nowhere, silly!';
```

This is meant to run with the `-r` flag, receiving the coordenates as the 1st and 2nd arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 107 bytes

```
a=>b=>if((a|b)==0)"That goes nowhere, silly!"else Seq("North ","","South ")(b+1)+Seq("West","","East")(a+1)
```

#### [Try it online](https://ideone.com/ERXRLb)

To use this, declare this as a function and call it:

```
val f:(Int=>Int=>String)=...
println(f(0)(0))
```

#### How it works

```
a =>                                // create an lambda with a parameter a that returns
  b =>                              // a lambda with a parameter b
    if ( (a | b) == 0)                // if a and b are both 0
      "That goes nowhere, silly!"       // return this string
    else                              // else return
      Seq("North ","","South ")(b+1)    // index into this sequence
      +                                 // concat
      Seq("West","","East")(a+1)        // index into this sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 103 bytes

```
f(a,b){printf("%s%s",b?b+1?"South ":"North ":"",a?a+1?"East":"West":b?"":"That goes nowhere, silly!");}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 130 bytes

```
String c(int x,int y){return x==0&y==0?"That goes nowhere, silly!":"North xxSouth ".split("x")[y+1]+"WestxxEast".split("x")[x+1];}
```

**Explanation:**

```
String c(int x, int y){               // Method with x and y integer parameters and String return-type
  return x==0&y==0 ?                  //  If both x and y are 0:
     "That goes nowhere, silly!"      //   Return "That goes nowhere, silly!"
    :                                 //  Else:
     "North xxSouth ".split("x"[y+1]  //   Get index y+1 from array ["North ","","South "] (0-indexed)
     + "WestxxEast".split("x")[x+1];  //   Plus index x+1 from array ["West","","East"] (0-indexed)
}                                     // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#hY4xb8IwEIX3/IrDQ2WLECUrKOrUEZYgdYgY3NQilowd@S5gK8pvD0awdKhY3g3v07tv6YxEhP2UASBJ0h005LU9Q8e1JQj5I6OYvKLRWwh1XX7EFJ/s2EuCs1MI1t165VUOqI2JK7ZlB@ephxAaN6bLChyMJs4CE21cV6c1@1ZIIXxJpD9lSOVuzpLMMP6YJPNyujr9CxepLX/atSeQ4uEM0EQkdSnSo2JIFRnLO17lUAmx@x8o3wFpYfN2onwCczYvyx0)

```
class M{
  static String c(int x,int y){return x==0&y==0?"That goes nowhere, silly!":"North xxSouth ".split("x")[y+1]+"WestxxEast".split("x")[x+1];}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(1, 1));
    System.out.println(c(0, 1));
    System.out.println(c(1, -1));
    System.out.println(c(0, 0));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
South East
South 
North East
That goes nowhere, silly!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 68 bytes

```
"
South 
North 

East
West"N/3/l~W%.=s_Q"That goes nowhere, silly!"?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#i67@r8QVnF9akqHA5ZdfBKK4XBOLS7jCU4tLlPz0jfVz6sJV9WyL4wOVQjISSxTS81OLFfLyyzNSi1J1FIozc3IqFZXs//vVWmrF/o/WNVTQNYzlAtEGEArEM4AIGoDFDMBCUHUQZSBVAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#i67@r8QVnF9akqHA5ZdfBKK4XBOLS7jCU4tLlPz0jfVz6sJV9WyL4wOVQjISSxTS81OLFfLyyzNSi1J1FIozc3IqFZXs//vVWmrF/o/WNVTQNYzlAtEGEArEM4AIGoDFDMBCUHUQZSBVAA)

Prints one trailing space on `[0 -1]` or `[0 1]` (`North` or `South`).

**Explanation**

```
"\nSouth \nNorth \n\nEast\nWest"  e# Push this string
N/                                e# Split it by newlines
3/                                e# Split the result into 3-length subarrays,
                                  e#  gives [["" "South " "North "]["" "East" "West"]]
l~                                e# Read and eval a line of input
W%                                e# Reverse the co-ordinates
.=                                e# Vectorized get-element-at-index: accesses the element
                                  e#  from the first array at the index given by the 
                                  e#  y co-ordinate. Arrays are modular, so -1 is the last
                                  e#  element. Does the same with x on the other array.
s                                 e# Cast to string (joins the array with no separator)
_                                 e# Duplicate the string
Q"That goes nowhere, silly!"?     e# If it's non-empty, push an empty string. If its empty, 
                                  e#  push "That goes nowhere, silly!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 100 bytes

```
f a,b{["That goes nowhere, silly!"]if[a=b,a=0]else[["","South ","North "][b],["","East","West"][a]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#ZU5BCsIwEDy3r1j3HME@oEevXhQ8xBw2dGsCNdEkRaT27TVpj8IyM8wszCw9kNCTxIuhBHfPEZx/Gw4sINph@OxQ2V5SqwW1B8VDZCkRBZ79mAxkcfKhCCW1EmtypJgyXTmTkqTUvDzIOpjqKvIL9o2ABr7Q@wAEna@rP1tvdvUco8nzcks5nfGWsARlNOj1JViXAIvbecf1hvPyAw)

This is a trivial solution, similar to some other answers.